# SBT: Exclude resource subdirectory

Tags: scala, gradle, sbt

I've been using Gradle for most of my Scala projects, but I want to evaluate the suitability of SBT as a replacement. One of the things I've done in Gradle is to exclude a certain resource directory from the final build (for example, using CoffeeScript to write JavaScript files that will be included as final resources).

In Gradle, I'd do this by:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            exclude 'com/example/export/dev' // exclude development resources
        }
    }
}
```

And this would exclude the resource package `com.example.export.dev` package from the final build.

How would I do the same in SBT? I've tried

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile -= (resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "com/example/export/dev"
```

but that doesn't do a thing (I understand why, but that doesn't really help). And the documentation on the SBT web site only talks about excluding file patterns (at [Classpaths, sources, and resources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Classpaths.html)).

As a more descriptive image, say we have the following resource directory structure:

```
com
\---example
     \---export
         \---dev
         \---something
```

In the final output, I want:

```
com
\---example
    \---export
        \---something
```

Comment: Do you want to exclude what is under the "resources" directory or do you actually want to exclude an entire java/scala package (with code) from the compilation?

Comment: I want so exclude a directory that is under the "resources" directory. Frankly, though, the Gradle version is flexible enough to also exclude an entire java/scala package from compilation, and it would certainly be nice if SBT could do the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jshint/issues/14:

```
excludeFilter in unmanagedResources := {
  val public = ((resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "com" / "example" / "export" / "dev").getCanonicalPath
  new SimpleFileFilter(_.getCanonicalPath startsWith public)
}
```

Comment: Let me test this out as well. If they have a hook already in place for filtering then definitely this is better than what I have.

Comment: And that works perfectly! Admittedly not ideal, since I'd really prefer to simply state a path on the excludeFilter (something like `excludeFilter in unmanagedResources := "com/example/export/dev/"`). So the situation really is there is no direct way to exclude a directory from compilation. It's disappointing, given how well SBT does most of the other things I throw at it, and given that directory exclusion seems to be one of those things you'd like to easily express.

Answer (score 7):

The way to think in SBT is a bit different and I know it can be hard at first.

In your example, you need to modify the task that generate the resource files (or the task that selects the folders to look for resource files).

Here is an example of how I can select only the resource files that start with character 'a'.

```
(unmanagedResources in Compile) := (unmanagedResources in Compile).value.filter(_.getName.startsWith("a"))
```

Similarly if you want to modify the entire directory of the resource files you can do that like this:

```
(unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile) := (unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile).value.filter(_.getName.startsWith("a"))
```

Obviously my filters here are just and example, you can have any complex pattern that Scala supports.

The nice thing about SBT is that it's interactive. So you can check the result of your task by simply typing these at the REPL of your project:

```
> show compile:unmanagedResources
> show compile: unmanagedResourceDirectories
```

To check all the dependencies to the task do this from the REPL:

```
> inspect tree compile:unmanagedResources
```

---

**Assumption:**

SBT knows where to find all resources using the standard [maven build directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). The above solution assumes that all resources are under the `/resources` directory. You can then access them from your Scala code using `getClass.getResource("/folderInsideResources/file.txt")`.

Here is a sample directory layout for a mixed Java/Scala project with resources:

```
 .
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── a
    │   │           └── b
    │   │               └── Hello.java
    │   ├── resources
    │   │   ├── a.tx
    │   │   └── b.tx
    │   └── scala
    │       └── com
    │           └── a
    │               └── b
    │                   └── ScalaHello.scala
    └── test
        ├── resources
        └── scala
            └── com
                └── a
                    └── b
                        └── ScalaHello.scala
```

To access the resource file just use:

```
 getClass.getResource("/a.txt")
 getClass.getResource("/b.txt")
```

Comment: I did note in my question that modifying `unmanagedResourceDirectories` didn't work. The reason (which I left out) is because `unmanagedResourceDirectories` points only to src/main/resources, and unless I manually recurse down the directory tree to set it (excessive for something this simple), I cannot simply exclude some directory under the resources directory. Can I simply conclude SBT doesn't have a simple way to say "Ignore this (source|resource) (subdirectory|package) when building/compiling", and I have to manually build up the resource/source list myself when I want to do this?

Comment: Oh, ok, now I see where the issue is. Well the right way is to add all your resources in the /resources folder (next to the java/ scala/ folders). You can then access them using: `getClass.getResource("/folderInsideResources/resourceFile.txt")`. In this way, all your resources are in one place and SBT will know how to manage them for you.

Comment: No, I want to ensure that when I build/run my project, that folder's resources don't get included. I've updated my question to show what I mean. Your first half of the answer was closer to what I wanted, but it doesn't work when I want to exclude a directory instead of just a file type.

Comment: Any particular reason why your resources are not in the resources folder and you have them mixed with your source-code files?

Comment: No, those resources are in the resources folder. They are not mixed with the source code at all. I just don't want them in the final build. For example, they may be files that compile to the real resources, but aren't the resources directly.