# Exclude generated source package directory in SBT project

Tags: java, scala, jaxb, sbt, xjc

I have an SBT project which uses the [sbt-xjc](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-xjc) plugin to create JAXB Java classes from the QTI XSD ([this one](http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1.xsd) in particular). My XSD has a dependency on MathML and it creates MathML classes as well as QTI ones as expected. The only xjc flags I am currently using are `-verbose -extension`.

Here's my directory tree:

```
- src/main/resources/imsqti_v2p1.xsd
- target
  - classes/org
    - imsglobal/... - Contains QTI .class files
    - w3_1998/math/mathml/... - Contains MathML .class files
  - src_managed/main/org
    - imsglobal/... - Contains generated QTI .java files
    - w3/_1998/math/mathml/... - Contains MathML .java files
```

However, I have another JAXB project with a dependency on MathML and that one also generates MathML classes. I want to get rid of the duplicate classes. I created a MathML JAXB project and added it as a dependency to the other 2 projects. How can I tell SBT to create a QTI autogen JAR which does not include the MathML classes?

I tried something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318321/sbt-exclude-resource-subdirectory), but it's not working. The MathML classes are still being included in the JAR. Here's my attempt that I added to my build.sbt:

```
val mathmlPath = "org/w3/_1998/math/mathml"
def isInPath(path: String, file: File) = file.getCanonicalPath.startsWith(mathmlPath)
(managedSources in Compile) := managedSources.value.filterNot(file => isInPath(mathmlPath,file))
```

I'll accept any of the below to get this to work:

1. Configure sbt-xjc to not generate MathML classes.
2. Configure sbt to not compile the MathML classes.
3. Configure sbt to not package the MathML classes.

Comment: Did you try to print your managed sources? do they contain the files you want to exclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `mappings` key to define the content of jar. See: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Package.html

In your case, you can exclude MathML files (assume they all starts with `org/w3_1998/math/mathml` in jar) by the following settings in `build.sbt`:

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filterNot {
  case (filePath, pathInJar) => pathInJar.startsWith("org/w3_1998/math/mathml")
}}
```

or less verbose (& less readable to some):

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filterNot(_._2.startsWith("org/w3_1998/math/mathml")) }
```